# how to merge dataframes of different sizes based on equal names when they appear more than once?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like bellow:

```
name    day
joe      1
paul     1
paul     2
joe      2
peter    2
```

and another one:

```
name    zip_code
joe      1000
paul     1001
peter    2002
```

I need to join the zip_code column to them and result on this:

```
name    day   zip_code
joe      1      1000
paul     1      1001
paul     2      1001
joe      2      1000
peter    2      2002
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.merge`:

```
df = df1.merge(df2)
```

Output:

```
    name  day  zip_code
0    joe    1      1000
1    joe    2      1000
2   paul    1      1001
3   paul    2      1001
4  peter    2      2002
```

Comment: This is a clear duplicate, rather flag it as one.